# Zenity (alike) File Browser with custom filesystem Root

Tags: filesystem, filemanager, zenity

I am creating ubuntu application which need to display file browser from command line, and request file selection from user.

I am aware usage of `zenity --file-selection --file-filter="MP3 Files | *.mp3"`

Using zenity script above should satisfy my need of requesting user selected mp3 file.

But aside from requesting file, I need to hide or prevent user from browsing the entire computer drive, like going to /home/myapp_user and see all the contents inside, or simply see the folders inside `/etc`, the rule is, user may only see whatever contained within /media directory.

Is there any tools (like zenity) to provide File Browser, but only at `/media` directory, in other words, I need to put the root directory to `/media` only. So for this file-selection-dialog, `/media` is the top directory and can't go up.

On java, this [link](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/single-root-file-chooser/) describes what I need.

As additional info, I am creating kiosk-alike application which lock down terminal, and other ubuntu application. But i still need to hide file system view on this file selection dialog.

this question is also asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279727/zenity-alike-file-browser-with-custom-filesystem-root . I'm sorry if this is considered as duplication.

Thank you.